# How to merge two tables that have the same schema into one, whith phpmyadmin

Tags: php, merge, phpmyadmin

I have two tables that have the same schema (tab1 and tab2), I would like to know how to merge them into one table, in a way to append tab2 under tab1.

I use phpmyadmin with WAMP.

**to sum up what i want:**

tab1

+tab2

= tab3 (tab3 = tab1 U tab2)

thank's

Comment: create table table3 like table1 ; insert into table3  select * from table1 ; insert into table3  select * from table2;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your first question, in phpMyAdmin, open tab2, Operations > Copy table, choose tab1, and select Data only.

If you really want a tab3, open tab1, Operations > Copy table (structure and data) to tab3, then open tab2, Operations > Copy table (data only) to tab3.

Comment: thank you so much, this method is really quick and useful, it works fine when schema is similar in the two tables.

Comment: Duplicate Entry Problem

Comment: @SirajuddinLuck Sorry, in phpMyAdmin there is no option in the Operations dialog to ignore a duplicate entry. However you could do it via a SQL command like suggested in the answer below, but using the IGNORE keyword. See https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-insert-ignore.

Answer (score 1):

**Query 1**

create new table with same structure using this query

```
create table table3 like table1 ;
```

**Query 2**

insert the old table values into new table like this

```
insert into table3 select * from table1 ;
```

**Query 3**

`insert into table3 select * from table2;`

note : if you have primary key and unique . data should be unique . otherwise it will throw the error .

Comment: Is it possible to do it graphically using phpmyadmin GUI ?

Comment: i don't know phpmyadmin have that facility or not but . by the above query it's possible i'm sure about it .

Comment: This helped me https://www.codehaven.co.uk/mysql/import-csv-to-phpmyadmin/

Answer (score 1):

- `newTable` *(Is empty and will contain the data from next two tables.)*
- `firstTable`
- `secondTable`

1. Go to `firstTable` -> Find -> Options and copy only data to `newTable`.
2. Go to `newTable` and memorize the last ID. *(e.g. 86)*
3. Go to `secondTable`, find SQL and run the following query:

```sql
UPDATE `secondTable` SET `id` = 86 + `id`;
```

4. From the same `secondTable` you go to options and copy only data to `newTable`.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new table that has all the records. In the bracket you have a union query that combines both tables.

CREATE TABLE tableAll 
(SELECT * FROM table1 UNION SELECT * FROM table2);